# Checkout Form isn't Submitting

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to submit the checkout form, but it is not submitting. It has values of products form cart (product name, code, price) and currently entered user data, and screenshot of DB table (orders) https://ibb.co/bbBHCky  ...... any solution to resolve it,..........,,,,,,,,.

**checkout.blade.php**

```php
<ul class="list-group mb-3">
    <?php  $total_amount = 0; ?>
    @foreach($userCart as $cart)
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
            <div>
                <h6 class="my-0">{{ $cart->product_name }}</h6>
                <small class="text-muted">Quantity: {{ $cart->quantity }}</small>
                <small class="text-muted" style="display: none;">{{ $cart->product_code }}</small>
                <small class="text-muted" style="display: none;">{{ $cart->product_id }}</small>
            </div>
            <span class="text-muted">Rs {{ $cart->price }}</span>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
        <span>Total (PKR)</span>
        <strong>{{ $total }}</strong>
    </li>
</ul>

<form method="post" action="{{ url('/checkout') }}" class="needs-validation" novalidate>{{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="firstName">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="name" value="" required
                   style="border: 1px solid black !important;">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Valid first name is required.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="email">Email </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com"
               required="required" style="border: 1px solid black !important;">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please enter a valid email address for shipping updates.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="1234 Main St" required
               style="border: 1px solid black !important;">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please enter your shipping address.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
            <label for="country">Country</label>
            <select name="country" class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="country" required>
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                <option value="usa">United States</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please select a valid country.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="state">State</label>
            <select name="state" class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="state" required>
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                <option value="cal">California</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please provide a valid state.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
            <label for="country">City</label>
            <select name="city" class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="country" required>
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                <option value="lhr">United States</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please select a valid country.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="zip">Zip</label>
            <input type="text" name="zipcode" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="" required
                   style="border: 1px solid black !important;">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Zip code required.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
            <label for="zip">Mobile</label>
            <input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="" required
                   style="border: 1px solid black !important;">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                mobile no required.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" style="background-color: black;">Place Order</button>
</form>
```

**ProductsController**

```php
public function placeOrder(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $data = $request->all();

        $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
        if (empty($session_id)) {
            $session_id = str_random(40);
            Session::put('session_id', $session_id);
        }

        $order = new Order;
        $order->id = $id;
        $order->name = $name;
        $order->email = $email;
        $order->address = $address;
        $order->country = $country;
        $order->state = $state;
        $order->city = $city;
        $order->zipcode = $zipcode;
        $order->mobile = $mobile;
        $order->product_id = $product_id;
        $order->product_code = $product_code;
        $order->product_name = $product_name;
        $order->product_price = $product_price;
        $order->product_quantity = $qty;
        $order->order_status = "New";
        $order->grand_total = $data['grand_total'];
        $order->save();

        return view('products.checkout');
    }
}
```

**Route**

```php
Route::match(['get','post'],'/place-order','ProductsController@placeOrder');
```

Comment: is there really a space in your Route 'place- order' ?

Comment: are you getting an http response at all or it's literally not being submitted?

Comment: no there is no space in my route and its not being submitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change form action to

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('place-order') }}" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
```

and remove space from route: '/place- order'

```
Route::match(['get','post'],'/place-order','ProductsController@placeOrder');
```

Comment: @programmer0001 try this solution

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Order' not found
  which is       $order = new Order;

Comment: Now go inside the function and the error is from something else. You should add the Order model with 'use' in top of the  ProductsController.

Comment: add this code: `use App\Order;` in top of the  ProductsController

Comment: @programmer0001 Error fixed or not?

Comment: added but still same issue nthing happened

Comment: You do not have the variables you have used, for example `$name` , If these variables are values of the form, you should use it as `$request -> name`

Comment: sory bro still same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187513/discussion-between-programmer0001-and-vajiheh-habibi).

Comment: This answer solved your original problem of the checkout form not submitting, you just have more  problems inside your action method now.  Look into test driven development where you can take small steps, ensuring everything works as you go.